# Frequency Axis of Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) with Odd Number of Data Points

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, frequency-response

I am trying to understand the logic behind making a frequency axis in DFT. I am using for time based light absorbance. When we have even number of data points (N= even integer), collected over a length of time A, the lowest frequency $\omega_1$ that can be resolved is 1/A, the next step is 2/A, the $k^{th}$ step is k/A, where *k* =1,2,3..., N/2. The highest frequency $\omega_{max}$ = N/2A based on Shannon's or Nyquist criterion. This the maximum value on the frequency axis.

How do we scale the frequency axis of FFT when we have odd number of data points (N+1) collected over a length of time A, where N is a even number? I cannot find similar reasoning for scaling when we have odd number of data points except in the book excerpt below.

[image: EDITS]

1. The step size of frequency in case of odd number of data points:  k/A whether the data points are even or odd.

Please see the excerpt from a book called DFT: An Ownwer's Manual by Briggs. What is the author trying to say when he says that the highest frequency $$\frac{N}{(2A)}$$ does not *quite* coincide with the endpoint of the frequency domain which have the values $\Omega$/2?**Please note that the author is using N as an even number.**

Is he indicating that there is a slight error when we have a DFT of an odd number of datapoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be answered simply by considering the *definition* of the $N$-point DFT:

$$X_N[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[k]e^{-j2\pi \frac {n}{N}k }$$

where it's easy to see that the DFT just compares your $N$-point input signal $x[k]$ to a sinusoid of frequency $\frac nN$.

Thus, the lowest frequency is always $0$, and the resolution is always $\frac{f_\text{sample}}{N}$, no matter whether $N$ is even or odd. That also means that the lowest non-DC frequency is also $\frac{f_\text{sample}}{N}$.

Comment: What is the maximum value of the frequency axis? Many authors say that the Nyquist frequency is omitted when we have odd number of data points?

Comment: Try to do a bit of your own math! What's the highest frequency with an odd $N$, e.g. $N=5$, knowing that the 0.th bin is $f=0$, and spacing is always $\frac{f_\text{sample}}N$? This is really no hard math. You should try to do it with a piece of paper.

Comment: sometimes @MarcusMüller , the one-sided expression of the DFT and iDFT can be a little confusing.  this is why i wish they had, in the very beginning, defined the DFT and iDFT as

$$X[k] \triangleq \sum_{n_0}^{n_0+N-1} x[n] \, e^{-j2\pi\frac{nk}{N}} $$

$$x[n] = \tfrac1N \sum_{k_0}^{k_0+N-1} X[k] \, e^{j2\pi\frac{nk}{N}} $$

where $n_0$ and $k_0$ can be any integers.

Comment: heh; usually I'm the one pestering people to first define what they're asking about :) yes, I agree, this is all a question of how you define the DFT. I just went ahead and used my definition, and was assuming that if OP doesn't agree with that definition, they'd tell me in the comments :) But yeah, you're right, one can define that base transform permuted by any means, and then the indices change; anyway, and that might be something I need to add if the differences between this and my "standard" definition are the hard part here: No matter what $n_0$ you choose, it's the same frequency set!

Comment: I have edited the question with an excerpt from a book, which is causing some confusion. This is DFT: An owner's manual by Briggs, just trying to digest some of the relevant content for utilitarian purposes. My background is analytical chemistry, where it is emphasized that the data points are power of 2^n. So far this is the only book, which explicitly talks about a difference between odd and even number of DFT.

Comment: sorry, there's no edit to your question? (also, again, there's no big difference about even and odd DFTs, which is probably the reason few books talk about it)

Comment: I had added the book excerpt with some highlighted text in purple. Not sure why the new edits did not appear then. From my side, I can see the new book text.

Comment: works now! However, that's not adding anything new; the highest frequency component is at $f_\text{sample}/2$, and that's not a multiple of $f_\text{sample}/N$ for odd $N$. There's really nothing specific about the DFT here, it's just basic multiplication…

Comment: Okay, thanks this is what I was trying to confirm. Let us say the sampling rate 200 Hz and we have 5 data points. The Nyquist frequency is 100 Hz by definition, but the frequency scale would read 0, (1*200/9), (2*200/9), ..., (5*200/9). The last point value is 111.11 Hz, which is above Nyquist limit. Which approach is strictly correct then, stop at the frequency axis at (4*200/9) =88.88 Hz or as some books suggest it round off for example in Matlab N=5, floor(N/2)+1, which means we stop at (3*200/9).

Comment: no, it's not. I don't understand why you're counting like this, where your 9 comes from. Again, your frequency spacing is $f_\text{sample}/N$ **always**.  $f_\text{sample}/N= 200\,\text{Hz}/5 = 40\,\text{Hz}$, in your case. I don't know why you're trying to make this complicated: The DFT divides the sample rate by the number of points. That's how it's defined. It's really that simple. There is no special case for odd lengths. The frequencies you're observing are 0, 40 Hz, 80 Hz, -80 Hz, -40 Hz. That's it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, thanks for your patience. On paper I was working on 9 points, and wrote 5 here to save space. It should have been N=5 just to be consistent, throughout, 0, (1*200/5), (2*200/5) for a one-sided spectrum. However in this case, the Nyquist limit of 100 Hz, is not a multiple, of this 40 Hz spacing as you stated earlier.

Comment: yeah, so what? What's problematic about that? What is surprising? We've established that really a couple of times now :)

Comment: Oh Nothing surprising or problematic!  Just clarifying the out of-nowhere 9 :-) Detailed FFT calculations on digital data should be a part of chemistry curricula. It is always a hand waving discussion even in PhD level chemistry courses - although it is almost a decade now, I am revisiting FFT for a project.